# Spring Data JPA : not persisting parent relation column mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Currently I am following this [URL](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-auditing-automatically-persisting-audit-logs)  & implemented the similar kind of code at my end.

But it gives an error at my end something likewise,

```
null value in column "file_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Here, category_id is one of my parent_entities primary key.

Following lines where parent entity I am passing properly & checked through Debug,

```
EntityManager entityManager = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
entityManager.persist(new FileHistory(target, action));
```

### **UPDATE -**

Here, instead of the following config,

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_file_history_file"))
```

I've used,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
```

Also, I used `@PostPersist` instead of `@PrePersist` these are the changes only I did against [this article.](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-auditing-automatically-persisting-audit-logs)

Comment: Show the entity configs

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Thanks for your reply. can you please refer UPDATE section. I have used it a little diffrently.